# List(of T) vs DataTable to fill a DB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, list, datatable

I have a windows forms application to automate certain tasks and one part is to fill a SQL Server table with large amounts of information (sometime is less to 10, but i see a situation with more than 1000 lines!)

Today i have a List(of T) to execute this task. "T" is a class with 8 strings parameters.

In the "Save" function i parse the List to construct a SQL Query to insert the information in one table.

But the process of inserting in the DB sometime take several seconds to complete, even if only a few lines to insert, especially under SQL server overload. Its better to use a DataTable with the 8 string columns to store the data and use to fill the database? I appreciate other suggestions too.

best regards

Comment: Inserting more than 1000 records can last some seconds. Is that too long? You could use a `DataTable` and set the dataadapter's [`UpdateBatchSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatebatchsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to 1000. That should be more efficient. But `SQLBulkCopy` is the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the VB side the structure used will not make a difference. 
If you want a faster method, you could look at the SQLBulkCopyClass to help you out.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Very interesting this SQLBulkCopyClass. Solve this problem, because accept a DataTable directly and appears to apply to another project i´m working where have several "excel to SQL" import classes. Only issue are certain external client DB, only accessible via WebService or VPN and need to pass plain SQL insert.